# iOS - In-App Purchase & applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, ios, in-app-purchase, launch

I'm working on an app for 4.0 using the background methods.  I'm updating the user defaults with a number that is incremented each time the app is launched.  Looks like in 4.0 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions doesn't fire each time the app is launched, only the first time it's launched if it's not already in the background.  So right now, my user default is incrementing within the applicationDidBecomeActive method.  Not sure if this is the right place.  I did the same thing with Flurry Analytics and some other stuff that I want to instantiate each time the app is "launched".

I noticed that during an in-app purchase the applicationDidBecomeActive method fires twice.  Not only is it falsely incrementing my user default as if the app was relaunched, it is also reinitializing flurry and the other items in the applicationDidBecomeActive method.

What am I doing wrong?  Should I be using another method each time the app is "launched"?

Thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could try `applicationWillEnterForeground` instead of using `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Comment: Won't that increment his launch counter even more inaccurately?